# R how to compare two columns for duplicates

Tags: r, compare

I have data with repeated observations that sometimes match on two elements but differ on a third, and sometimes match only on the first. For example:

```
name <- c("John", "Mary", "Anna", "Anna", "John", "Mary", "Anna", "John")
sport <- c("soccer", "basketball", "tennis", "tennis", "soccer", "soccer", "badminton", "basketball")
time <- c(41, 5, 10, 61, 1, 12, 18, 99)
data <- cbind(name, sport, time)

name    sport       time
John   soccer        41
Mary   basketball    5
Anna   tennis        10 
Anna   tennis        61 
John   soccer        1
Mary   soccer        12
Anna   badminton     18
John   basketball    99
```

For each observation that matches on the first two columns (e.g. here, on both name and sport), I want to keep only the observation with the greatest time value. For those that match only on the first column (e.g. name), I want to keep them as is. For example:

```
name    sport       time
John   soccer        41
Mary   basketball    5
Anna   tennis        61 
Mary   soccer        12
Anna   badminton     18
John   basketball    99
```

How would I do this?

Comment: `as.matrix(as.data.frame(data) %>% group_by(name, sport) %>% top_n(1, time))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion, instead of what you have:

```
data <- data.frame(name, sport, time)
```

Execute below to see what's happening

```
sapply(data, class)
```

`cbind` by default coerces everything to class of character, you don't want that.

I am summarizing the values (time) by grouping 
on name and sport and naming the variable `time`. also use na.rm = T to exclude cases in your data where you might have a missing value in variable time

```
#dplyr version
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(name, sport) %>%
    summarize(time = max(time, na.rm = T))
```

Aggregate suggested in the comments above works as well, but I find dplyr syntax easier to read

Comment: *`cbind` by default coerces everything to class of character, you don't want that.* I am not aware of that behaviour. can you point me to your reference? I know the following tho: ***The cbind data frame method is just a wrapper for data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE). This means that it will split matrix columns in data frame arguments, and convert character columns to factors unless stringsAsFactors = FALSE is specified.***

Comment: p.s. found it!!!

Comment: This is great & very helpful. Thank you!!